# How to merge a subdirecgory a of repo A to repo B, perserving all commits of the repo A?

Tags: git

Say I have git repos A and B.

I wanna somehow copy the **directory a** under repo A to repo B, with the same directory name, also with all relevant commits to all files under the **directory a**

Is this possible (for merging an external repo partially with commits)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories?

Comment: @potatopeelings this one is different, it's about merging a whole repo to another.

Comment: just thought it might be helpful if you didn't get any answers. Cheers!

Comment: Read *all* the answers in the linked question. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50191809/1256452) is particularly relevant to the way you've described your desired outcome.